# Junit pass some values from @Test methods into a @Rule method

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I use Junit to run tests as part of Selenium framework. I need to record some values from the actual test methods into another method.

```
    @Rule
  public final RuleChain rules =
      RuleChain.outerRule(
              Watcher.newBuilder()
                  .addCustomProperty("key", "value")
                  .addCustomProperty("key", "value")
                  .addCustomProperty("key", "value")
      );

 @Test
  public void someTest() {
   String a = "newValue";   //this need to be passed into @Rule "value"
   String b = "newValue";   //this need to be passed into @Rule "value"
   String c = "newValue";   //this need to be passed into @Rule "value"
}
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here. But why not set the values as instance attributes of the test class and pull them in the rule?

Comment: Although, testing best practices say that JUnit tests should be self contained and not depend on each other. Given that they can be executed in random order...